# Try to get selected value from multiple selected value

Tags: php, html

I have form where I select multiple values. Its showing selected value but along with that its showing error
Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1559

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1559

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1571

Notice: Undefined offset: 5 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1571

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1559

Notice: Undefined offset: 4 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1559

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1571

Notice: Undefined offset: 6 in /var/www/lo/g8_tool/g8_gusr/test.php on line 1571

```
for($g8_i=0;$g8_i<$g8_count;$g8_i++)
{
  if($g8_j!=count($g8_groupY_arr))
 {
  if($g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i] == $g8_group_y[$g8_j])
 {
   $g8_selected = "selected";
   #echo $g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]."<br>";
    $g8_j++;
    $g8_str.="<option value=".$g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]." ".$g8_selected.">".$g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]."</option>";
    } else
    {
        $g8_selected = "";
        #echo $g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]."<br>";
        $g8_str.="<option value=".$g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]." ".$g8_selected.">".$g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]."</option>";
     }
    #$g8_str.="<option value=".$g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]." ".$g8_selected.">".$g8_groupY_arr[$g8_i]."</option>";
    } else {
             break;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Where does `$g8_groupX` originate from? Is it `$g8_groupX = $_POST['g8_grpX'];`? Also, you have a stray `';` that is throwing off the code markup. Is it supposed to have a `$g8_str.= '`?

Comment: Code is correct I think I have a problem in two for loops

Comment: You didn't close your php code before typing the html codes. Can you show the html result of this php code?